# How to download multiple table files using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning selenium and one of the challenges is to download files from certain rows from a table, how do I do this?
first I checked the lines that have the information "Em aberto" and then I found the file download button, but I can only download the file from the first line.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()

link = "https://app.hdkjfl.com/v2/login"

navegador.get(link)

user = "*****"

password = "******"

sleep(1)

campo_user = navegador.find_element_by_id('login-input-usuario-id').send_keys(user)

campo_password = navegador.find_element_by_name('senha').send_keys(password)

button_enter = navegador.find_element_by_id('login-button-id').click()

sleep(10)

button_consultas = navegador.find_element_by_id("menu-consultas").click()

sleep(3)

iframe = navegador.find_element_by_id("iframeRf")

navegador.switch_to.frame(iframe)

sleep(2)

fatura = navegador.find_element_by_id("consultaspnl.row.8").click()

sleep(2)

items = navegador.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="dataBaseTD nomeTD"]/div[text()="Em aberto"]')

# print(items)

sleep(1)

#arquivo = items.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="g.image.visualizar"]').click()

# print(arquivo)

for item in items:
    #print (item)
    item.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="g.image.txt__bsp__v2"]').click()
```

HTML 1 code:[html 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6R0v.png)
HTML 2 code:[html 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WYJM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about correctness of your locator, just copy-pasting it.
I just added the `.` at the beginning of the XPath to select element inside the `item`, not the first one.
Try this:

```
for item in items:
    #print (item)
    item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="g.image.txt__bsp__v2"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

The delay may be essential between the clicks to let the download complete

Comment: I putted the point but appears this message: **NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id="g.image.txt__bsp__v2"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.164)**

Comment: and after removing the point, I managed to download the various files, but it's the same file, it's not other files.

Comment: Since you didn't share the link to the page I have no idea what locator should be there. I just used what you wrote

Comment: look this : [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H0Np7KwDAkyZgVcfejF0v9135Y7JbCWC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share a link to the web page, not just HTML code?

Comment: I can send you the link, but you won't have access to the part where I'm having a problem. https://app.reservafacil.tur.br/v2/login?returnUrl=%2Finicio